# saving bank row using array

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamic form which allows to add multiple textboxes. While saving the data in the database, it also saves an additional empty extra row. Could you help to find the issue?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="skill[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill name, e.g. HTML">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="percent[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill proficiency, e.g. 90">
      <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 duplicateable-content">
  <div class="item-block">
    <div class="item-form">

      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-float btn-remove"><i class="ti-close"></i></button>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="skill[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill name, e.g. HTML">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input name="percent[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill proficiency, e.g. 90">
              <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my php to save the data input:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["skill"]); $i++) {
  $skill = $_POST["skill"][$i];
  $percent = $_POST["percent"][$i];

  $sql = "insert into tb_skill (skills,percent,user_id) values 
    ('$skill', '$percent', '$_SESSION[id]')";
  mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You likely need to trim a newline character off the end of your input... at least that's at first glance.

Comment: @Roble, can you please paste here POST array values, how they are coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help to you.

```
  $skill = $_POST['skill];
    $percent = $_POST['percent'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < = count($skill); $i++) {

      $sql = "insert into tb_skill (skills,percent,user_id) values 
        ('$skill[$i]', '$percent[$i]', '$_SESSION[id]')";
      mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines inside of your for loop, before you submit the variables to database.

```
$skill = trim($skill);
$percent = trim($percent);
```